# How to set Parse Installation Class security (class-level permissions and/or ACL)?

Tags: security, parse-platform, push-notification, acl

I'm developing a Parse App and currently checking the backend security. I'm a bit lost regarding the Installation Class permissions. It is (by default) readable and writable by everyone. Thus, any user could delete every object of the class.

My question is: is it protected by default like the User class? Or should I add ACL for every new registration to push notifications? Or change the class level permissions?

Many thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse defaults to public read/write access for everything outside of `User` to streamline development.

Security measures will vary from one app to another depending on use-case, but assuming that you have associated each `Installation` to a `User`, I would highly recommend applying an ACL which gives public read and limits writes to the specific user.

In case you are not already associating each `Installation` to a `User`, here's a nice piece of cloud code to take care of it for you.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    if (request.user) {
        request.object.set('user', request.user);
    } else {
        request.object.unset('user');
    }
    response.success();
});
```

It's a good place to start by creating ACLs which provide public read and user-specific write access. That one step alone will drastically improve security.

Comment: Hi @Russell, thanks for your answer! I've set the ACL directly in the App code, right before saving the installation.